# How does one go about creating shapes in perspective for a logotype?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am constantly looking for new things to try out in Adobe Illustrator to improve my skills, and I came across this:

[image: artwork]

I've no idea how can this be created and would appreciate some help.

I tried creating a white box, apply a thick stroke and then skewing it, but I ended up with a mess that looking nothing like that :/

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add that. Added.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method.

1. Draw a rounded rectangle
2. Transform > Shear > 30° vertical
3. Copy and paste the shape
4. Select both and apply 50 step Blend (or enough steps to make it solid)
5. Expand twice, Pathfinder Unite, to make a single shape
6. Copy and paste the shape, and draw smaller shapes (see red outlines) to cut out parts of one of the shapes
7. Use Pathfinder Minus Front to remove the parts
8. Draw additional shapes with the Pen tool

[image]

Comment: nice, this one looks easier! I'll try it when I get home and report back, thank you very much!

Comment: there is a easier way. you dont need step 3->4 you can ujust use a calligraphuc brsh on 2 directly. Ping for @Ciwan too

Comment: @BillyKerr how do you create the bit in step 8?

Comment: @Ciwan, these were just drawn with the Pen Tool, I made one, then copied and pasted it.  The single rounded corner on the left shape was created with the rounded corner widget available in Illustrator CC

Comment: @joojaa how does one apply the calligraphic brush? I'm lost at step 3 because I don't know what a step blend is or how to apply it

Comment: @Ciwan A step blend is achieved by selecting two objects to blend, then using Object > Blend > Make, then click  Object > Blend > Blend Options to change it to a step blend. Joojaa I think is talking about applying a calligraphic brush to a stroke instead. Simply select a path, and apply a calligraphic brush by clicking on it. I think this approach would also work well.

Answer (score 1):

Only some guidance, obviously you want to find the details yourself:

[image]

Draw a square, add effect "Rounded corners"

Add effect 3D > Extrude & Bevel, preview=ON, no shading, no bevel, the view = Isometric Left. Play with the extrusion depth

Expand the appearance. You get a 2D shape which have the needed curves and anchor points to add more parts. I removed the fill and drawed a green rectangle. It snapped perfectly with snap to points and smart guides ON. Disable other snaps, or you get nothing usable.

You can tweak the effects via the appearance panel as long as they aren't expanded.

You must also subtract parts. That can be done using

- boolean operations in the Pathfinder panel or
- adding clipping masks or opacity masks
- direct path anchor point editing tools and the scissors

You must release the compound path and ungroup the groups before you can edit the expanded shape.

Altough you can often get wanted shapes very fast, 3D effects can be considered as Pandora's Box approach, a shortcut to unnecessary complexity which easily turns to unmanageable => Before trying this explore direct 2D drawing as suggested by others.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I'll try this when I get home and report back.